# How to create partitions in Kafka Topics with customer name/id

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, confluent-platform

I am trying to create topics with 100 partitions and I want each partition to have a unique name or id so producer knows exactly which partition to use to send the event. I am using Confluent Kafka so I used UI to create a topic with 100 partitions but it did not provide me an option to choose the name or any key for the partition?

Here is the link that I am following: https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/control-center/topics/create.html

Language: .NET

Is there a way to specify/customize the partition id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't name partitions in Kafka, only topics have names. Partitions are always numbered starting from 0 for each topic.

You can either use 100 topics with different names or use a [`Partitioner`](https://kafka.apache.org/30/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/Partitioner.html) that computes the partition number of each event.

Comment: How do I make sure from the producer end that the message goes to the same partition. Is it based on the key of the message?

Comment: The default Partitioner ensures message with the same key end up in the same partition. But you can still get multiple keys in the same partition.
Partitioner is a pluggable interface, so you can write your own if the built-in Partitioners don't satisfy your use case.

Comment: Can the event key be in a json format? Because we need multiple ids to distinguish the event so can I send the key in json format?

Comment: The record key can be any arbitrary data, exactly like the value.